# R neuralnet training for a simple dataset of squares of numbers

Tags: r, neural-network

Dear neuralnet experts,

I am studying ANN with a book and R package.
One of the examples is to train a neuralnet (R package) for a simple set of squares of numbers [1~10]. It was quite quick and easy to fit them with 1 hidden layer with 10 neurons.
But, for a large set of [1~30], the algorithm does not converge. I think that some parameters should be changed to train the neuralnet. At first, I increased the number of neurons and hidden layers, i.e, c(20,10). But, failed...
Could somebody please guide me to learn more about neuralnet to train the dataset?

My code in R is given as,

```
library("neuralnet")

#Read the input file
mydata50=read.csv('Squares50.csv',sep=",",header=TRUE)
mydata30 <- mydata50[1:30,]
attach(mydata30)
names(mydata30)
mydata30

#Train the model based on output from input
model30=neuralnet(formula = Output~Input, 
                data = mydata30, 
                hidden=c(20,10),
                threshold=0.01 )
print(model30)

#Lets plot and see the layers
plot(model30)
```

Best regards,
Dong-Ho